# Android Studio Google maps fragment Buttons

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio

Hey guys :D i got a question, is it possible to add some buttons to the google map activity on android studio? And if its possible ... can some one tell me how ? I tried it like on a normal or Blank activity but wont work lol :/

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574657/android-cant-get-relative-layout-to-align-to-parent-bottom .. and the answer should work for you.

Comment: Two other things: 1) show your code. just saying "it wont work lol" is not going to inspire people to help you help yourself 2) do some research before you post a question - there are LOTS of results for this search query

Comment: Tyvm for your reply :) and sorry cause of the Code... But im a newbie lol Need to learn

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify the [UI controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity) in the Android Maps API. You can not add customize control through. But you can create custom control elements with the [Javascript Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls), just use a webview to include the page if you needed.

Otherwise, you might able to get some idea by looking at this too: [Android: Overlay on Android Camera Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466336/android-overlay-on-android-camera-preview)